# PostgreSQL Connection Pooling with NpgSQL

Tags: postgresql, connection-pooling, npgsql

I am writing a program (Basically a TCP Server), that collects data from IoT devices and store them into database. This is in C# and I have used the NPGSQL library to interact with PostgreSQL.

I have created a simple class to execute DB related actions. Here is the part of the code in the DB class that is of our interest

```
public class DB
{
    private readonly NpgsqlDataSource _DataSource;
    private static DB? _instance;

    private DB()
        {
            IConfiguration config = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").Build();
            string? connectionString = config.GetSection("ConnectionString").Value;
            if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(connectionString)){
                throw new Exception("ConnectionString not foud in appsettings.json");
            }
            var dataSourceBuilder = new NpgsqlDataSourceBuilder(connectionString);
            this._DataSource = dataSourceBuilder.Build();
        }
    
        public static DB GetInstance(){
            if(DB._instance is null){
                DB._instance = new DB();
            }
            return DB._instance;
        }

       public async Task<int> ExecuteQuery(string sql){
            var command = this._DataSource.CreateCommand(sql);
            return await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
       }
}
```

Rest of the methods are all static. The code is self explanatory. I am basically creating a datasourcebuilder only once.

Now when ever sockets connect and send data I do many database transactions using other DB class static methods like DB::GetInstance().ExecuteQuery() and such.

Here is my connection string

```
Host=***;Database=***;Username=***;Password=***;
```

Now every now and then I am getting a "Too many clients" error. I am not working the connections directly and letting NGPSQL to handle the connections and connection pooling.

Here is a snap of a function (in the program) that will show how I am using the DB Class and interacting with database.

```
public async Task<string?> OnTrackerData(List<TrackerData> trackerData)
    {
        foreach (var data in trackerData)
        {
            await StoreData(data);
        }

        if (trackerData.Count > 0 && this.TrackerId > 0)
        {
            string sql = "SELECT id, command FROM tracker_commands WHERE tracker_id = " + this.TrackerId + " AND processed_at IS NULL ORDER BY requested_on ASC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0";
            Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader trackerCommandsRecordSet = await DB.GetInstance().ExecuteReader(sql);
            if (trackerCommandsRecordSet.Read())
            {
                sql = "UPDATE tracker_commands SET processed_at = " + Utilities.GetCurrentTimeStamp(330) + " WHERE id=" + trackerCommandsRecordSet["id"].ToString();
                await DB.GetInstance().ExecuteQuery(sql);
                return trackerCommandsRecordSet["command"].ToString();
            }
        }
        return "";
    }
```

Everywhere in the prgram, I am interacting with the database using the DB class with the above code pattern. Except DB class, I am neither creating nor using the connection directly in my code anywhere. Even I am not opening or closing connection anywhere in my code. I am letting NPGSQL handle it completely.

Interestingly I am getting this every very frequently. Say as soon as I do 50 - 60 transactions (query) with the database server. I am not sure where I am NOT DOING IT CORRECT, so that there is a problem with connection pooling.

## Update

max_connections at posgre server is set to 100
and
Maximum Pool Size=50 in connection string

I don't understand why so many physical connections are opened by NPGSQL. Should not it keep a connection in pool and reuse it? We have a high volume traffic on this application. Lots of IOT devices keep sending data every seconds or so. I am lost here. Don't know how to configure it properly to handle that high database transactions.

Comment: Check the `max_connections` configuration on the PostgreSQL side - that's the maximum number of allowed physical connections, ensure that the Npgsql `Max Pool Size` is lower than that (I'm assuming there's only one client with Npgsql running). Otherwise you may be leaking connections somewhere (e.g. forgetting to dispose), a runnable, minimal code sample would help investigate more.

Comment: Hi @ShayRojansky I have added some more code that will show how I am interacting with the database through the DB class only. Postgre is running with default configuration and NPGSQL is also with its default configuration. I am not sure why NPGSQL is creating so many physical connections and not using connection pooling.

Comment: You're not disposing your NpgsqlDataReader, so the connection can't be returned to the pool. Add `await using` on the line that calls ExecuteReader.

Comment: As a side note, you should avoid concatenating strings into your SQL (`WHERE tracker_id = " + this.TrackerId`), this can make your application vulnerable to SQL injection attacks and is inefficient. [See this section](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/basic-usage.html#parameters) in the Npgsql docs.

Comment: Really bad mistake.. I was scratching my head.. My Bad.. Yes, those SQL statements are temporary. I am not going to keep those these way.. Thank you for helping ! Let me close the readers and hopefully, I'll be all set.

Comment: I'd suggest never doing this even in temporary SQL statements - temporary things have a tendency of becoming permanent, and this is a real security issue. I'd advise getting familiar with parameters and always using them systematically.

Comment: Yes, already converted them to parameterized query and thank you for pointing the issue. !